# http://localhost domain name unusable after installing new adsl router

Tags: router, localhost

I have Apache installed and the server directory index was accessible using http://localhost before I recently installed a new Dlink ADSL2+ Modem+Router . Now the apache web server contents are only accessible using the address 127.0.0.1 in the web browser. Using http://localhost displays a "403 Forbidden (nginx)" message. When I unplug my ethernet cable from the PC and restart networking , localhost leads to the apache index.

I have tried assigning a new domain name 'localwebserver' in the /etc/hosts file to 127.0.0.1 but then the browser displays a message "Critical error: no domain selected!"

My **/etc/hosts** file

```
127.0.1.1 avinash-ubuntu
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 localwebserver

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

My **/etc/network/interfaces** file

```
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

`nslookup localhost` :

```
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   localhost.home.network
Address: 185.53.179.7
```

What could possibly be changed when I plug in the new router? How can I get localhost to display the apache index? Haven't found any option on the modem config page that seems related (to my knowledge)

Thanks

Comment: Could you share result of `nslookup localhost`

Comment: I have added it in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your DHCP server add search directive in your `/etc/resolve.conf`. And host with name `localhost.home.network` exist in Internet, so you try to connect to it instead of your host. Try to change DHCP configuration on your router(change domain from `home.network` to something else, like `myhome.local`).

Comment: I am not sure how that setting was affecting this but I changed the interfaces setup to static for now anyways and the search entry has been removed from resolv.conf. Works fine now, thanks

Comment: Microsoft discourages (as do I) using the TLD .local - the proper method is to use a domain or subdomain you have full control over.